# How can I interrogate the value of DAY when retrieving SYSDATE?

Tags: sql

From my question you may conclude that I'm a NEWBE, but please know that I have searched various sites (Ask Tom, Oracle, BC Computing, etc) and Stack Overflow for an answer and I'm not quite getting what I need;  Which is the ability to interrogate the DAY portion of the SYSDATE column:

I am retrieving the SYSDATE month and day using the statement:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD') 
  FROM DUAL;
```

The result is, for instance, 06-27.  Now I want to use the DD value to SELECT from a different table.  For example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD') 
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE DD = '15'
       SELECT * 
         FROM MY_PERSON_TABLE;
```

However DD isn't a valid column name on DUAL, so I'm not sure how to use the day in my query.  I tried using a CASE clause with WHEN, but I think I just got more confused.

Answer (score 0):

for the day you simply can use DD

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') FROM DUAL
```

and from any table you can

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') FROM MY_PERSON_TABLE
```

DD in this case is not a column but a parameter for the date formatter ..so you can use in every date column .. or system date

eg:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') FROM MY_PERSON_TABLE
WHERE TO_CHAR(my_column_date , 'DD') = '21'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the day as a *number* rather than a *string* the easiest way is to usre the [`EXTRACT` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(day FROM SYSDATE)
FROM DUAL
```

Selecting the day as a number makes certain operations easier, like comparing to existing data (since you don't have to worry about padding with zeros or spaces, etc.)